# React navigation - Navigation action = back

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to use the back action from react navigation to dismiss a modal as follow:

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back({
    key: this.props.navigation.state.params.previousKey
}));
```

I pass the key of the previous screen when navigating to the modal:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ModalScreen', {
    previousKey: this.props.navigation.state.key
});
```

But nothing happened.

When I don't use key, the navigationaction.back dismiss the modal properly back to the previous screen when calling the function by clicking on a button.

But when I call it from the constructor, it sends back to the root screen...

Any idea?

**EDIT 1**

Trying another approach with custom action as follow. When I reload the app and try it, it works properly the first time. But when I try a second time without reloading the app then I get the error: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined.

**in my router.js file:**

```
const CheckInStack = StackNavigator({
    CheckIn: {
        screen: CheckIn,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
            headerLeft: null,
            gesturesEnabled: false,
        }
    }
});

export const SiteStack = StackNavigator({
    Site: {
        screen: Site,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
            headerLeft: null,
            gesturesEnabled: false,
        }
    },
    CheckIn: {screen: CheckInStack,},
}, {mode: 'modal', headerMode: 'none'});

const prevGetCheckInStateForAction = SiteStack.router.getStateForAction;

SiteStack.router = {
    ...SiteStack.router,
    getStateForAction(action, state) {
        if(state && action.type === "DISMISS_MODAL") {

            console.log('in router');

            const routes = state.routes.slice();
            routes.pop();
            return {
                ...state,
                routes,
                index: routes.length -1,
            }
        }
        return prevGetCheckInStateForAction(action, state);
    }
};
```

**in my screen.js file:**

```
componentDidMount() {

        const {profile} = this.props.auth;

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-user.' + profile.id );

        channel.bind('App\\Events\\Order\\SiteHasAnsweredCheckIn', event => {

            // this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back()); => this is where the back actions is launched. nowhere else.

            //CUSTOM ACTION DISPATCH
            this.props.navigation.dispatch({
                type: 'DISMISS_MODAL'
            });

        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution here: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/686

from richardfickling on github.

In my router.js, I create a DismissableStackNavigator as follow:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
export default function DismissableStackNavigator(routes, options) {
  const StackNav = StackNavigator(routes, options);

  return class DismissableStackNav extends Component {
    static router = StackNav.router;

    render() {
      const { state, goBack } = this.props.navigation;
      const nav = {
        ...this.props.navigation,
        dismiss: () => goBack(state.key),
      };
      return (
        <StackNav
          navigation={nav}
        />
      );
    }
  }
};
```

And then my checkin stack is as follow:

```
const CheckInStack = DismissableStackNavigator({
    CheckIn: {
        screen: CheckIn,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
            headerLeft: null,
            gesturesEnabled: false,
        }
    }
});
export const SiteStack = StackNavigator({
    Site: {
        screen: Site,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
            headerLeft: null,
            gesturesEnabled: false,
        }
    },
    CheckIn: {screen: CheckInStack,},
}, {mode: 'modal', headerMode: 'none'});
```

And then in my CheckIn screen:

```
componentDidMount() {

    const {profile} = this.props.auth;

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-user.' + profile.id );

    channel.bind('App\\Events\\Order\\SiteHasAnsweredCheckIn', event => {

        //method coming from the Dismissable Navigator stack
        this.props.navigation.dismiss();

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will solve your problem, but you could try to use the goBack method instead of dispatching the back action. Like this : 
`this.props.navigation.goBack()`

Comment: I'll try this one. Thanks. But the documentation says that a navigators navigation prop may not have the helper function. Not sure to sure to understand this exception.

Comment: no improvement. Basically, sometimes it is dismissing the modal and go back to the screen underneath and sometimes it is dismissing the modal, go back to the screen underneath and then go back to the main screen. No logical pattern...

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling the back action two time in a row ? Also, I have had some weird behaviors with the navigation when I was testing in debbug mode. Try it in release.

Comment: I've checked but no luck. Now trying a new approach with custom actions. Please see the Edit above in my initial question. Works the first time. Then I get the error: cannot get property routes of undefined on my state variable I guess... So still not working.